# How to add a snippet to new line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to make a key snippet to add time and current file name using `keybindings.json` file.

So i am using this code

```json
[ 
    {
        "key": "alt+t",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": 
        {
            "text": "\n",
            "snippet": "$TM_FILENAME/*$CURRENT_YEAR-$CURRENT_MONTH-$CURRENT_DATE         $CURRENT_HOUR:$CURRENT_MINUTE:$CURRENT_SECOND*/"
        }  

    }
    
]
```

output That is being received is

```
sdfgv.cpp/*2023-07-26 11:32:14*/
```

But i want to add **`$TM_FILENAME`** in a new line.

So How can i do that any solution ?

Comment: show the output you expect

Comment: `text` is not a used argument for `editor.action.insertSnippet`

Comment: @rioV8  ```filename``` and in new line 
```date and time of creation```

Comment: if you don't type/show what you want it makes it hard for us to guess and it is easier than a ton of words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this keybinding to insert a line and then your snippet:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+t",
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      "editor.action.insertLineAfter",
      {
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": {
          "snippet": "$TM_FILENAME/*$CURRENT_YEAR-$CURRENT_MONTH-$CURRENT_DATE         $CURRENT_HOUR:$CURRENT_MINUTE:$CURRENT_SECOND*/"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It first inserts a line below the cursor and then inserts the snippet on that newline.

[image: insert snippet on line below the current line]

---

If all you want to do is insert the filename where the cursor is and then, on the next line, the date information, then use this keybinding:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+t",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "$TM_FILENAME\n/*$CURRENT_YEAR-$CURRENT_MONTH-$CURRENT_DATE         $CURRENT_HOUR:$CURRENT_MINUTE:$CURRENT_SECOND*/"
  }
}
```

Note the `\n` after the fileName will insert a newline - thus going to the next line.

Comment: showing error :(

Comment: I tested it as you can see it running in the demo.  What error are you getting?  And the keybinding is within the outer `[]` of your `keybindings.json` file.

Comment: i want that in a new line file name and then time of creation in new line

Comment: You want fileName on one new line and the time on the next line?  Or filename on the current line and the time on the next line?

Comment: yes | first ```filename```   and then in a new line ```date and time ```

Comment: I edited the answer to insert the filename at the cursor and the date info on the next line.